# Polyfill vmlaq_lane_f32 for Webassembly

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten, neon

Webassembly doesn't currently support FMA instructions and `vmlaq_lane_f32` fails to compile with Emscripten. So far I came up with the code below but there's no such thing as `vaddq_lane_f32` and `vaddq_f32` works on all lanes so it's not the best solution.

```cpp
      float32x4_t vmlaq_lane_f32(float32x4_t a, float32x4_t b, float32x4_t c, lane) {
            return vaddq_f32(a, vmulq_lane_f32(b, vget_low_f32(c), lane));
      }
```

Second issue is lane must be const and the above doesn't work as a standalone function so I have to replace every instance manually.

One more problem is that multiple files should include this definition and the compiler errors out due to redefinition in o. files.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE there are 3 questions here, 1. how to correctly polyfill vmlaq_lane_f32 for webassembly 2. lane must be const, how to make it parametrized 3. how to have multiple .o dependencies import this declaration and not error out due to a conflict

Comment: 1. Only the Cortex-a8 doesnt't have fmla. Maybe you can ditch it to enable fmla. 2. Lane number has to be an immediate value by definition. And thus, you can't put it in a short loop. Simply unroll the loop. 3. You could use #ifdef in C, maybe there's  something similar in webassembly

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions
1. This is not native code, can't chose any targets and it simply doesn't compile with Emscripten
2. I'd prefer to not modify the source code of the library I use only write some polyfill for it to run
3. Tried #ifdef and it worked with individual libraries but once they are built to .o files and included together it errors out due to conflicts inside built libraries